# Leader election implementation for libp2p

Tags: consensus, go-libp2p

I have a P2P system in Go using libp2p (this is in evaluation) running in a local network. This P2P system has to be provisioned with external data. The idea is to pull the data from a central server from some node and this node is then publishing the data into the local network. The node responsible for the data pull must be elected somehow and I'm searching for leader election algorithms which can be used with libp2p. I found a [Raft](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p-raft#section-readme) based solution, but I just need the leader election part of it and not the log store part of Raft. For Paxos I have found no implementation. What are the options for this problem?